# Using Tkinter's askopenfilename() with matplotlib not working in GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a GUI for my program and I would like the first step be that the user selects an image, which is then displayed on the GUI. The program works if I put a file path directly into it, but when I use askopenfilename(), the other buttons and places for user input no longer work. I had a full working GUI before askopenfilename(). Here is the part of the code that's giving me trouble:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from PIL import Image
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')

#since I added askopenfilename() I can no longer type in these boxes
e = Entry(window)
e.pack()
ee = Entry(window)
ee.pack()

#path = 'image.png'   #this was working fine
path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
img_arr = plt.imread(path)
img = Image.open(path)
```

I think it's an issue with matplotlib trying to read it, because the image opens, but I can't do anything with it. I believe the main issue is that I have created 2 dialog boxes that I can no longer type in. Has anyone ever had this issue?

Comment: is the `askopenfilename` window openned ? you have to select a file to get past it.

Comment: @AhmedAEK yes, it's opened and I can select the image and it displays in my window. But after that my application is unusable. I will try the debugger

Comment: @AhmedAEK the main issue is that I have two user entry windows in which to type values, and once the image is opened I can't type in them. I don't know why using askopenfilename would do this though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`askopenfilename` starts `tk.mainloop` early, if it wasn't already running, which messes up any created `Tk` object.

the solution to this is to either

1. create a hidden `Tk` object then call `askopenfilename`,then destroy it before creating your application's main `Tk` object.
2. or use `askopenfilename` after you start your application's mainloop, you can delay the calling of a function using `window.after` or by tying the logic to a button on the screen that the user presses.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

dummy_window = tk.Tk()
dummy_window.withdraw()
path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
dummy_window.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(master=window)
entry.insert("0", path)
entry.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Creating and destroying the dummy window fixed my issue